# Swashbuckle - How do I change the displayed title of the service?

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

When I run a .NET Core service using swashbuckle, the title it displays (above all the resources) is derived from the assembly name.

**How can I specify my own title to appear on the swagger page?**

(The title displayed on the page is distinct from the document title, which can be modified via `options.DocumentTitle` passed into the `app.UseSwaggerUI()` method.)

edit: This is my current setup code - it's what comes out of the box with the C# `webapi` template:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(opt => opt.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo
{
    Title = "Title of the service",
    Description = "Description of the service"
}));
```

[image]